# c# wpf how to set the cursor in WPF textbox like tabindex in windows form?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get the cursor in the WPF TextBox. so user does not click in the text box before typing like tabindex in windows form
thanks for helping

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the focus manually, you should just set the focus like this:

```
textBox.Focus();
```

You need to give the TextBox the name "textBox" for this. It is not an MVVM way, but should do the trick...

Comment: Thank you Marcel  I just want to add that  textbox.Focus();  be add  after the .xaml,cs file after InitializeComponent();
           textbox.Focus();    again thank you Marcel for your help

Comment: textbox.focus() put the caret in the textbox but did not take entry  so i have to click before begin typing I tryed Textbox.TabIndex=0 but doesnt work

Comment: @awadallahayman Sorry, but I think I don't understand what you are trying to do... maybe you should look for a basic course of WPF in your country?